# Java "cannot convert from element type Object to String"

Tags: java

```
/*     */   public static void printJoinChat(Player player) {
/*  41 */     FileConfiguration kitConfig = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(new File(plugin.getDataFolder(), "kit.yml"));
/*  42 */     List kitname = kitConfig.getStringList("KITS");
/*     */ 
/*  44 */     String vipkit = "";
/*  45 */     String norkit = "";
/*  46 */     for (String name : kitname) {
/*  47 */       ConfigurationSection kit = kitConfig.getConfigurationSection(name.toLowerCase());
/*  48 */       if (kit.getBoolean("VIP")) {
/*  49 */         if (vipkit == "")
/*  50 */           vipkit = name;
/*     */         else {
/*  52 */           vipkit = vipkit + ", " + name;
/*     */         }
/*     */       }
/*  55 */       else if (norkit == "")
/*  56 */         norkit = name;
/*     */       else {
/*  58 */         norkit = norkit + ", " + name;
/*     */       }
/*     */ 
/*     */     }
```

This code returns the error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to String" at line 46. Why does this error come up?

Comment: you should specify `List<String> kitname` or else it will be taken as an `Object`

Comment: Start compiling with -xlint, then the compiler will tell you about things like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change to this:

```
 List<String> kitname = kitConfig.getStringList("KITS");
```

Make sure that method returns a `List<String>` and not just a `List`.